# Dielectric Grease on Electrical Connections

Tags: electricity, conductors, dielectric

The electrical connection between my truck and our RV trailer was intermittent. When I wiggled the connection the errant light would go on and off, so I bought some electrical grease and problem solved, but a question surfaced. Why is “electrical grease” a dielectric rather than a conductor? Here’s a photo of the package.[image]

Comment: I've used this sort of grease for the outdoor electrical connections of my lawn's sprinkler system. I don't think that the purpose of this grease is to immediately improve electrical contacts but rather - as the package you showed says - to protect the electrical contacts from corrosion. So I don't think that this grease helped any in giving you a better electrical connection. However, it will help in the long term in ensuring that corrosion due to outdoor weather won't degrade your electrical connection.

Comment: In addition to preventing corrosion from humid or corrosive environments, dielectric grease has other uses: lubricating the contacts, so they mate more reliably and don't get stuck; and absorbing vibration. It's likely that a combination of these two properties is what improved the reliability of your connection. The grease also helps keep dirt and dust from getting in between the contacts and prevents shorting between adjacent pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grease is a composite material.  Some electrical greases are loaded with
conductive particles (silver, copper, graphite).   Other electrical grease and 'contact enhancing' coatings employ semiconductor components   [contact enhancer](https://www.google.com/patents/US4696832).   Yet other electrical greases
are simply intended to reduce contact-surface wear in sliding connections or
exclude oxygen so that arcing does not produce ozone.

The phrase 'dielectric grease' means that small amounts of the material
will not create unwanted electrical conduction paths, which is important in some applications.   It is a label that has no known strict
definition, but it does exclude conductive-particle loaded products.